# Kindle Fire HD not playing youtube video using iframe in a web view

Tags: video, youtube, playback, kindle

I am trying to play a YouTube video on a KindleFire by loading

`<html><body><iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HS78vzEVA28?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"/></html></body>`

in a WebView. It works fine on Kindle Fire 1st gen, but on the Kindle Fire HD it loads the video thumb and the red overlapping play button but once clicked the video does not play.

Any suggestions how the get the video to play ? Thanks.

Comment: see my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095552/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-webview-on-amazon-fire-tv/31257689#31257689

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest have you enabled hardware acceleration for the webview, and specified the WebChromeClient rather than just take the default for the webview hosting the HTML - see https://gist.github.com/3718414 for samples. I tried your youTube clip and it works fine (switches from Flash, which isn't supported on the FireHD, to HTML5 video playback but works fine)